# Is it ok to use biology microscope for gemological purpose?

Tags: mineralogy, minerals

Is it ok to use biology microscope for [gemological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemology) purpose?

What's the difference?

Comment: Most biological microscopes work by light transmission - light passes through the specimen from below.  This doesn't work well with most rocks.

Comment: It mostly depends what exactly is the thing you want to do. There are many kinds of biological microscopes and there are many "gemological" things you can do.

Comment: @Michael, for example: I'd like to find mineral flaws. What "gemological" things can't be done with biological microscope?

Comment: If it's a transmitted light microscope (light comes from below), you may be able to detect some mineral flaws, depending on your skill, the quality of the microscope, the mineral in question and the type of flaw. There is no definitive answer to your question.